# Unable to recognise an css/xpath element in protractor

Tags: javascript, html, css, xpath, protractor

Having a little issue when trying to find an element using Protractor #JasmineJs

I have this element:

```
<div class="x-editor x-small-editor x-grid-editor x-grid-cell-editor x-layer x-editor-default x-border-box" id="ext-comp-1325" style="right: auto; left: 338px; top: 51px; z-index: 19000; display: none;">
<table class="x-field x-table-plain x-form-item x-form-type-text x-field-default x-container-form-item" cellpadding="0" id="textfield-1324" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 79px;"><tbody><tr role="presentation" id="textfield-1324-inputRow" class="x-form-item-input-row">
<td role="presentation" id="textfield-1324-labelCell" style="display:none;" valign="top" halign="left" width="105" class="x-field-label-cell">
<label id="textfield-1324-labelEl" for="textfield-1324-inputEl" class="x-form-item-label x-unselectable x-form-item-label-left" style="width:100px;margin-right:5px;" unselectable="on">
</label>
</td>
<td role="presentation" class="x-form-item-body  " id="textfield-1324-bodyEl" colspan="3" style="width: 100%;">
<input id="textfield-1324-inputEl" type="text" name="orderConfigurationData_localTaxID" class="x-form-field x-form-text" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false" data-errorqtip="" style="width: 100%;">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Tried to find this text field (name="orderConfigurationData_localTaxID") with both

CSS:

```
let reqelem = element(by.css("input[name='orderConfigurationData_localTaxID']"));
    browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(reqelem), 10000);   
    reqelem.isDisplayed().then(null, function(err) { 
      console.error("An error was thrown! " + err);
    });
```

and Xpath:

```
let reqelem = element(by.xpath("//input[@name='orderConfigurationData_localTaxID']"));
    browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(reqelem), 10000);   
    reqelem.isDisplayed().then(null, function(err) { 
      console.error("An error was thrown! " + err);
    });
```

But ended up with "NoSuchElementError" in both the cases.
How can I retrieve this element since it is available in the dom.

[Snapshot of the DOM where the element is present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45a52.jpg)

CSS Error:

```
An error was thrown! NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, input[name='orderConfigurationData_localTaxID'])
```

Xpath Error:

```
An error was thrown! NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(xpath, //input[@name='orderConfigurationData_localTaxID'])
```

Comment: Use id - element(by.id("textfield-1324-inputEl")); in place of css and xpath

Comment: If you are trying to pick the element from the table generated dynamically, Try adding `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true)` which waits for the table to get loaded.

Comment: @parthi: ID is dynamically generated. so wouldn't be able to use it in this case.

Comment: @madhan: Its a static table and I have added 10 seconds after the table is loaded and 10 seconds before locating the element as well. Also, I have increased it to 20 seconds, ended up with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Found the answer why NoSuchElementError was triggered.

Issue is, Initially the field isn't editable. At this point the field/grid cell remains greyed out (Only to human eyes but not actually at the backend) which is an tabular element. So, the user has to click on the field/grid cell (which makes it editable) allowing him/her to enter values.

The DOM generates the above said elemental tags only upon clicking on corresponding tabular element first.

Below is the code which resolved the Issue.

```
//Click on corresponding tabular element first.

    element(by.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[contains(@class,'orderConfigurationData_localTaxID')]/descendant::div")).click();

//GridCell is editable now and we can pass the input.

    let reqelem = element(by.css("input[name='orderConfigurationData_localTaxID']"));
    browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(reqelem), 10000);   
    reqelem.isDisplayed().then(null, function(err) { 
    console.error("An error was thrown! " + err);
      });
    reqelem.sendKeys('56428');
```

Answer (score 0):

Locator seems to be fine.Can you check if any iframe is located in the page.

(or)

In browser.wait increase max time more than 10 seconds.

Comment: Yes, I did verify and there is no iFrame to be switched. Also, increased the browser wait time as 20 seconds ending up with no luck.

Comment: Use protractor debugger and try locating the element in debugger console.

Comment: Found the answer and posted the same as Official answer Bharath.

Comment: Well done but you should be doing the steps manually several times before start scripting

How ever you solved by yourself appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf` instead of

```
ExpectedConditions.presenceOf
```

The element might be present in DOM but not visible.

Comment: Found the answer and posted the same as Official answer @Sanja.